# Java Scheduler? (Add tasks etc.)

Tags: java, task, scheduler

Good Day,

Is there any API for Java where I can "add" tasks like an OS? I have a ExecutorService that runs every 1 minute, and during this tick, I need it to send about 10 TCP messages to multiple sockets.

I currently have a function that goes sendMessage(string data,string ipAdd,int port)
I was wondering if there is an EASY API for me to simply go taskScheduler.addTask(sendMessage(..)) in a loop say 10 times for 10 different data, and I am guranteed for them to executed all simultaneously?

Thanks

Comment: [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)?

Comment: ...define "simultaneously" - most schedulers have some sort of max-threads limit

Comment: Why an `ExecutorService` for this when there is [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)?

Answer (score 1):

yes there is. have a look at [quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

its really not difficult to set-up:

```
// Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory 
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

// and start it off
scheduler.start();

// define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)
    .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .build();

// Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 40 seconds
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .startNow()
    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
            .withIntervalInSeconds(40)
            .repeatForever())            
    .build();

// Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: I dont wish to download a new lib for this..could i use a thread pool?

Comment: there's the timer class - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html - but its nowhere near as reliable

Comment: See fge comment under you question for `ScheduledExecutorService`